# Do Apple Watch + Mathematica integrations still work?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I tried to follow this blog post: [Instant Apps for Apple Watch](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/28/instant-apps-for-the-apple-watch-with-the-wolfram-language/), but none of the examples given worked, instead, they would simply hang on the "loading" screen.

[image]

Can anyone verify if this functionality is currently still supported?

Infrequently I will get this screen instead:

[image]

Comment: Upvote for nice wrist. :)

Comment: Thanks @yode, but it's not nice enough to make the app work :(

Comment: Did you email tech support?

Comment: Yah, no response yet

Comment: I tried it not too long ago and it wasn't working for me either. I assumed it was in my error so I didn't pursue it past that, this makes me think that there must be some other issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can only say, it still works for me (2018-04).
Of course, the watch has to have connectivity with the iphone, which has to have connectivity to the Mathematica server - and the server has (but not too often) times of overload, I guess. Ah, and some content can indeed not be displayed on the watch, e.g., animations, I think.
I only recently finally delved into deploying my own Mathematica WatchApps - that still works too.
One time the Mathematica WatchApp froze completely (on the script selection list) - a reinstall of the app helped.

Comment: And as it seems, just a few weeks after I wrote this, Wolfram Cloud for Apple Watch has been discontinued :-( The answer from Wolfram support did not sound as if it would sometime soon be supported again, too. ;-(